# Select numbers between a range (1 to 100) in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I know some of the solutions in SQL but couldn't find any of them from SQlite.

I just want to execute a select query that returns a resultset of numbers ranging from 1 to 100.

```
Numbers
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ......
  5
```

A correction:  I don't actually have a table at all. (however a solution is encouraged with a virtual table like `dual` in MySQL)

Answer (score 46):

Thanks sgmentzer! 
Inspired by your answer I went ahead and also found [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT x+1 FROM cnt
      LIMIT 100000
  )
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```

Comment: Need Sqlite version at least 3.8 do use WITH. Btw, `RECURSIVE` and `(x)` are optional: `with cnt as (select 1 x union select x+1 from cnt where x<100000) select x from cnt`

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber >= 1 AND myNumber <= 100;
```

?

Comment: yes it fine if table `mytable` exists but i don't have a table at all.

Comment: Why not just create a loop in the programming language you are using?

Comment: @BastiBen Because it's more efficient with lots of rows, for example, if you have millions of rows, you have to retrieve them, loop through them and then displaying them. This takes more time than a direct query selecting the items you want

Answer (score 5):

Example subquery to generate the series 1 <= n <= 100000 in SQLite. No table is created or used.

```
select 1+e+d*10+c*100+b*1000+a*10000 as n from
(select 0 as a union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9),
(select 0 as b union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9),
(select 0 as c union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9),
(select 0 as d union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9),
(select 0 as e union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9);
```

Comment: And without using the `WITH` keyword (which still isn't supported by Adobe Air's version of SQLite)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think SQLite has a clean way to do this, so you'll need to use a virtual table interface. SQLite ships one for 'C', and apsw has one for python as I'll demonstrate below. Here's documentation for the [APSW Virtual Table interface](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/vtable.html).

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import apsw,tempfile

### Opening/creating database
filename=tempfile.mktemp() #insecure - do not use in production code
connection=apsw.Connection(filename)
cursor=connection.cursor()

# This gets registered with the Connection
class Source:
    def Create(self, db, modulename, dbname, tablename, *args):
        schema="create table foo( dummy integer )"
        return schema,Table()
    Connect=Create

# Represents a table
class Table:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def BestIndex(self, constraints, orderbys):
        used = []
        self.constraints = []
        ucount = 0
        for c in constraints:
            if c[1] in (
                         apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_GT, 
                         apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_GE,
                         apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_LT,
                         apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_LE,
                         apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_EQ,
                       ):
                used.append( ucount ) #tell sqlite we want to use this one
                self.constraints.append( c[1] ) #save some for later
            else:
                used.append( None ) #skip anything we don't understand
            ucount += 1
        return ( used,    # used constraints list
                  0,      # index number - no biggie we only support one right now
               )

    def Open(self):
        return Cursor(self)

    def Disconnect(self):
        pass

    Destroy=Disconnect

# Represents a cursor
class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, table):
        self.table=table

    def Filter(self, indexnum, indexname, constraintargs):
        start = 0
        self.end = 4000000000
        #map constraint arguments to start and end of generation
        for tc, ca in zip( self.table.constraints, constraintargs ):
            if tc == apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_EQ:
                start = ca
                self.end = ca
            elif tc == apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_LE:
                if self.end > ca:
                    self.end = ca
            elif tc == apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_LT:
                if self.end >= ca:
                    self.end = ca
            elif tc == apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_GE:
                if start < ca:
                    start = ca
            elif tc == apsw.SQLITE_INDEX_CONSTRAINT_GT:
                if start >= ca:
                    start = ca
        self.pos = start

    def Eof(self):
        return self.pos > self.end

    def Rowid(self):
        return self.pos

    def Next(self):
        self.pos+=1

    def Close(self):
        pass

# Register the module as intsource, you can make a bunch if needed
connection.createmodule("intsource", Source())

# Create virtual table to use intsource
cursor.execute("create virtual table uints using intsource()")

# Do some counting
for i in cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM uints WHERE rowid BETWEEN 1 AND 100"):
    print i
```

This implements a virtual-table type named "intsource", which by default counts from 0 to 4*10^9. It supports directly filtering by equality and comparison, but any other constraints will still be filtered out by sqlite. Virtual tables are a very powerful concept you can do a lot with, this is probably one of the simplest uses for them. Also, thank you for a good excuse to try out a new virtual table API.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Numbers limit 1, 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 100;
```

This is more efficient than using 2 WHERE clauses.

Comment: Sorry i don't actually have a table at all

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to select actual records from a table with values between 1 and 100, use BETWEEN as shown by the other respondents.

If your goal is to generate a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100 without having a table to base it on, I don't believe SQLite has a feature that does this.

Comment: yes it's fine if table mytable exists but i don't have a table at all.